# WooCommerce Add Shipping Class to 1000 Products

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce

I've just updated my WooCommerce Shipping Classes to work better with free shipping on certain items.

However, I need to apply my new 'Standard Shipping' class to 1000+ Products. Going through **Products > Bulk Edit** can't handle selecting them all at once, nor 100 at once, I don't want to resort to going through 10 by 10 until I know there's no other way of doing this.

**Question: Is there an SQL query that can speed this up?**

I can't seem to find where in the database the Shipping Class is kept for each product :(

Answer (score 3):

1. In screen option at top of the page choose to show 1000 products per
   page and remove all other fields except title.
2. Select all products
3. Bulk Edit

Comment: > Question: Is there an SQL query that can speed this up?

Answer (score 2):

I made this plugin, it loops through all the products of a certain category(s) and assigns the desired shipping class, more details are in the comments:

```
<?php
/*
Plugin Name: Bulk Shipping class update
Description: Bulk Update of shipping class for woocommerce products
Version: 0.0.1
Contributors: svelandiag
Author: svelandiag
Text Domain: woocommerce-ship-class-by-cat
*/


// If this file is called directly, abort.
if ( ! defined( 'WPINC' ) ) {
    die;
}

// define the woocommerce_init callback 
function action_woocommerce_init( $array ) { 
    /** The category ID's with the posts you want to change */
    $category_ids = array(635, 1022, 289, 291); // array of ints or single int
    
    /** The shipping class to set for the products */
    $shipping_class_slug = "shipping-class-slug"; // found in "shipping classes" in woocommerce settings
    
    /** Run query to collect our data */
    $products = new WP_Query(array(
        'post_type' => 'product',
        'posts_per_page' => -1,
        'fields' => 'ids',
        'tax_query' => array(
            array(
                'taxonomy' => 'product_cat',
                'field' => 'term_id',
                'terms' => $category_ids,
                'operator' => 'IN'
            )
        )
    ));
    
    /** Set our shipping class on each product */
    foreach ($products->posts as $pid) {
        wp_set_object_terms($pid, $shipping_class_slug, 'product_shipping_class');
    }
    
    /** reset the query */
    wp_reset_query();
}; 
         
// add the action 
add_action( 'admin_init', 'action_woocommerce_init', 10, 1 );

?>
```

You can also extract the hook and the callback and add it to your `functions.php` of your child theme, be careful this is a one-time use snippet since it runs every time admin backend initializes.

**The plugin has been tested with the latest Woocomerce to date 4.x and latest WordPress 5.x as well.**

Comment: I've been waiting 6 years for this. I'll give a test and see if it works!

Comment: It is tested up to Woocomerce 4.x and the latest WordPress version.

Comment: @svelandiag thanks.This is very usefull.How to change for multiple shipping classes? ex:  shipping class 1 set to product category1 , shipping class 2 set to product category2 and ...