# Bulk change shipping classes in WooCommerce

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce, hook-woocommerce

I've updated my WooCommerce shipping classes to accomplish a task with certain products being more expensive to ship. Weight is not possible as different shipping classes may have same weight.

Now I need to apply this shipping class to a lot of existing variations and not all variations in a specific category as [this posts answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/63025874/16089269) suggest.

```
/** Run query to collect our data */
    $products = new WP_Query(array(
        'post_type' => 'product',
        'posts_per_page' => -1,
        'fields' => 'ids',
        'tax_query' => array(
            array(
                'taxonomy' => 'product_cat',
                'field' => 'term_id',
                'terms' => $category_ids,
                'operator' => 'IN'
            )
        )
    ));
```

How can I modify this bit of code so it only apply to variations with pa_right = 'no'?

I tried getting inspiration from [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42497051/get-the-product-variations-attributes-values-term-id-and-name) but that didn't help me unfortunately

Comment: Why not use the csv importer ? https://docs.woocommerce.com/document/product-csv-importer-exporter/

Comment: Thank you @Bhanu - this made me try it out, and despite not being quite as effective as I was hoping I found another plugin that could do the trick for me among many other things :)

Answer (score 0):

You can use Woocommerce REST API.

1. Get all products
2. Change Shipping Class for all product
3. Update all products

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/late-answers/31832573)